# Maximum Number of User Per Mapping In ODI12c

Tags: etl, oracle-data-integrator

I am new to ODI. While working i ODI Project, I am facing one issue.

I have 10 mappings In ODI12c,and all are using same target table,but due to some performance issue, I want that at a time only max 2 users can Execute mappings(Max 2 mappings), since they are using same target table. If more then 2 user uses that same target then it should not execute.

How should I implement this in ODI12c?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something, but not exactly what you said. You can setup and option called "Concurrent Execution Controller" and tell a scenario to wait until it's previous execution it's finished.

So, you can do the next:

1.create a package

2.create scenarios for all the mappings

3.create a variable

2.inside the package call a scenario (no matter what scenario) and at the scenario name, put the variable (see image below)
[image: scenario_name_dynamic]

3.generate scenario for package

4.double click on the scenario of the package and choose "Limit Concurrent Executions" then choose Wait to Execute and then setup the Wait Polling interval to X seconds to wait

5.execute the package scenario and when the variable it's prompted, complete the name of the mapping you want to be executed
[image: Limit Concurrent Executions]

Please tell me if you need more info.