# Multiple users issue on same table

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have 10 mappings In ODI12c,and all are using same target table(single table),but due to some performance issue,i want that at a time  max 2 users can Execute mappings(Max 2 mappings), since they are using same target table,if more then 2 users uses that same target then it should  not be executed.How can i implement this in ODI12c?

Comment: hi, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767310/maximum-number-of-user-per-mapping-in-odi12c/56017072#56017072) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are these mappings executed in different packages or the same?

This is a lock-release question.
Depending on your details, you will need to have your mappings have access to a lock mechanism (i.e. increasing/decreasing a variable stored in a db) to manage the maximum amount of parallelism.
Pay attention to failing scenarios though that can leave the lock closed forever.

If they are in the same package, just execute 2 at a time and wait for children

Comment: All these mapping are in same Package.

Comment: In this case it should then be sufficient to have the package execute 2 mappings (in the form of asynchronous scenarios) and then wait for children. Repeat this for as long as you have mappings to execute